# sql query group by month and id. where id number should in one column by comma separator

Tags: postgresql

I would like to group by month and id( in one column by comma) like:

| Month | total | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 6 | (1,3,5,6) |
| Feb | 7 | (1,3,5,6,9) |

Answer (score 0):

```
select month, sum(detail) as total, sting_agg(id, ',') as id
from my_table
group by month
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, 
Its showing error as ERROR: function string_agg(bigint, unknown, bigint) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 116

Comment: Yes, please change datatype in string_agg: select month, sum(detail) as total, sting_agg(id::text, ',') as id
from my_table
group by month